# Rails microsevices JWT auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, authorization

I have two services **app1** and **app2**.

**App1** use **devise_jwt** for auth.

**App2** don't have web-ui, but provide only some api-data.

Is there a way to setup sso from **app1** to **app2**?

Some examples to clear what i'm talking about:

1. I auth in **app1**, go to page where **app2** data is shown (`app1.com/app2data`), ajax-request to `app2.com/data` is fired to retrieve JSON, **app2** check JWT and give me it's JSON-data
2. I go to `app2.com/data`, it redirects me to `app1/login`, authenticate and redirect to `app2.com/data`

Or maybe there is more simple ways to secure data in **app2** service?

Comment: (1) I thought you said App2 doesn't have a UI. So why, in your second example, do you say you "go to `app2.com/data`"? (2) Why not just do all of the interaction on the back end? User logs into App1. All data is pulled from App2 as needed via back end API between App1 and App2.

Comment: @jvillian ```app2.com/data``` return json-data. Ok, data can be pulled from App2 in controller, but how forbidden external calls. Main idea is to allow App1 user get data from App2, but no one else.

Comment: Use an API key. You can roll your own. Or use something like doorkeeper. The most appropriate solution depends on your use case.